# Oozie email action truncating the string containing newline chars

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I've this output captured from the shell action:

```
SHELL_OUTPUT='John,28,1,0
Jack,32,0,15
Mary,45,23,12
Jill,33,12,55'
```

The email action uses this captured output in the body like this:

```
Data: ${ wf:actionData('shell-c23f')['SHELL_OUTPUT'] }
```

But the email received seems to be truncated and only sending the first line instead of the complete string, for example:

```
Data: John,28,1,0
```

How do I go about making sure the complete string is part of the body of the email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action output is treated and parsed as a serialized java.util.Properties object.
You can test out what works for you easily by using  a Properties object and fool around with it.

E.g. something like

```
SHELL_OUTPUT='John,28,1,0 \
Jack,32,0,15 \ 
Mary,45,23,12 \ 
Jill,33,12,55'
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer, this worked for me:

SHELL_OUTPUT='John,28,1,0\n\
Jack,32,0,15\n\
Mary,45,23,12\n\
Jill,33,12,55'